# Detect ksh array support in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

Is it possible to write a `/bin/sh` shell script that detects whether or not the underlying shell supports ksh-style arrays? The latter are supported at least in ksh and bash, and in zsh with an option.

Comment: Why don't you simply run i.e. ksh, if you want to have ksh features?

Answer (score 0):

Since `sh` does not allow arrays, and there is no concept of a *underlying shell*.

Of course it is possible that on your platform, /bin/sh is symlinked to some other shell, or (as it happens on my symstem) is a copy some other shell (i.e. someone has performed a, say, `cp /bin/bash /bin/sh`).

To test for a symlink, you could do a `ls -l /bin/sh` and investigate its output.

To test for equality, the best you could do is to loop through the candidate shells you are considering, and test for equality. For instance:

```
for s in bash ksh
do
  if cmp -s /bin/sh /bin/$s
  then
    echo /bin/sh is in reality a $s 
    break
  fi
done
```

Of course there is no guaranteed way that it works.

Another possibility would be to run (perhaps using `eval`) some code fragments which use bash arrays, respectively ksh arrays, and analyze the stderr of it to detect, which ones gives syntax errors.